# Can't save user data under firebase user ID - Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

Can anyone please help me identify why I can't seem to save my user data in my web app's firebase database? I have done the necessary linking and even changed the database security rules to read/write to all. But still nothing. What do I do? Below is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="mdl-grid">
            <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>    
                    <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--6dp ">
                        <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-color--primary mdl-color-text--white">
                            <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text" style="left: 60px;position: relative;">User Information</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">

                            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="user_name"/>
                                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">User Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="walletaddress"/>
                                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Bitcoin Wallet Address</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                            <div class="mdl-grid">
                                <button id="savebtn" class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color-text--white">
                                    Save Information
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#savebtn").click(
function() {

    var username = $("#user_name").val();
    var wallet_address = $("#walletaddress").val();

    var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    if(email != "" && password != ""){

    firebase.database().ref().child('Users').child(uid).set({
    username_id: username,
    address_wallet: wallet_address
});

    }

}
);
```

I would want to save data in this format;

```
Users {
  userid {
    username: blah blah,
    address: blah blah
  }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Does it write to the database in the wrong structure? Does it not write to the database at all? If the latter, did you check your JavaScript console for relevant error/warning messages?

Comment: It doesn't write at all to the database. I checked my JavaScript console and found nothing. It was blank. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do I have to create the node before it will write to it? Cos my database is actually empty

Comment: Okay so I just realised that email and password are not variables. My bad. So I changed them to username and wallet_address. And still the data is not written to my database.

Comment: Okay so I changed my browser and used Chrome instead of Opera and it just worked. Wow

Comment: Ouch. That's surprising. Good find. Can you [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for that?

Comment: Definitely Sir. Thanks a lot again.